# WatiN Inner <HTML> Tag

Tags: c#, html, tags, watin

I'm trying out `WatiN` to test a site.
The site structure looks somewhat like this:

```
<html>
...
<ElementContainer src=...>
<html>
...
<body>
<table border=0>
... // I want to click things in here.
</table>
...
</body>
</html>
</ElementContainer>
...
</html>
```

I have no problem getting to the element container:

```
ElementContainer<Element> a = (ElementContainer<Element>)browser.Element(Find.BySrc("Source here")); // get Container
```

But the problem is,  `a.Elements[0]` *throws* `IndexOutOfBounds`.
I suspect WatiN treats `<html>` as something else...

My question is - what is that thing, and how can I access it?

**Edit**:

The second Html body is created via the following JS:

```
<script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      googTr = new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        multilanguagePage: true,
        gaTrack: true,
        gaId: 'UA-1307731-4',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
      }, 'google_translate_element');
      if (typeof(googleTranslateElementFullyLoaded) !== 'undefined') {
          setTimeout(googleTranslateElementFullyLoaded, 1000);
      }
    }
    </script>
```

**Edit 2**: I tried to write the InnerHtml of the ElementContainer... It printed a single space.

Comment: If HTML is not valid does it really matter that much how it fails? - Have you considered to construct valid HTML in first place?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The HTML is perfectly valid - It's a pretty famous site i've been hired to test, which I did not create and I cannot change.

Comment: No, it's completely invalid. you have **TWO** `<html>` blocks, nested. an html file can only ever have **ONE** `<html>` block.

Comment: @MarcB If it's relevant, the second one is created via Javascript.

Comment: If you want to see more of the code, i'll be glad to share - anyhow, the site **is** up and running right now.

Comment: Do you wait long enough for JavaScript to finish before searching for the element?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have a `Thread.Sleep(500);` after I press the button which spawns the HTML, and I can see that it takes the page much less to load the element.